# Will deleted images be safe in thumbnails folder?

Tags: xiaomi, delete

If I delete images with file explorer from DCIM/Camera and images are still in DCIM/thumbnails, will thumbnails images stay there? If they stay there, will something delete them in future? Does Xiaomi phones have something to delete thumbnails?

Comment: Hello. Why do you need thumbnails if you don't want their corresponding images? Alternatively, why do you care about them if they would remain or not? Those thumbnails are generated by your device's stock gallery app provided by Xiaomi. Do take into account that the source code of that app is not available in public domain and therefore, the answer you are likely to receive (yes/no) is going to be observational and version dependent.

Comment: @Firelord Hello. My friend deleted images from Pictures folder, and image is still in thumbnails folder. He is calling thumbnails folder "copy of images that take storage space" so he deleted original.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't expect the system to keep thumbnails of images I've deleted. I assume it should clear it from time to time. However, I don't know how Xiaomi handles those folders...

Comment: Your friend has wrong understanding of thumbnails! That said, I think Xiaomi's default gallery app has some sort of trash/recycle bin feature which doesn't acually delete the images in first instance. See if you can access that. Restore the images then. Otherwise, if you have sync setup for photos hope that those pictures were synced up with your account before being nuked by your friend. Lastly, don't give your phone to this friend of yours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thumbnails are not really the exact images you deleted. They are just the cached images of extremely low quality which your phone used to show you images with more speed. Your phone save a Thumbnail of image you open in your phone so that next time you open that image, it takes less time. Thumbnails have very small resolution and quality than original.
Clearing your cache memory will delete the thumbnails. Usually, phone don't have any automatic thumbnails deletion.